# relative link failure in ie8

Tags: vba, scripting, ms-word

```
Private Sub RenameHyperLinks(d As Document)
'
' RenameHyperLinks Macro
'
'
    Dim oFld As Field
    Dim oldString As String
    Dim newString As String
    Dim dp As Object
    Dim link As Hyperlink

    Set dp = d.BuiltInDocumentProperties

    'Set Base Hyperlink for document to relative path
    dp("Hyperlink base") = "..\"

    For Each oFld In d.Fields
        For Each link In oFld.Result.Hyperlinks
            If Left(link.Address, 10) = "\\fileserv" Then
                newString = RegExpSubstitute(link.Address, "^.*\\(.*)$", "$1")
                newString = RegExpSubstitute(newString, GetExtension(newString), "htm")
                link.Address = Replace(link.Address, link.Address, newString)
                link.TextToDisplay = Replace(link.TextToDisplay, link.TextToDisplay, newString)
            End If

        Next link
    Next oFld
End Sub
```

This is the vba code I am using to make absolute links inside of my document relative. I am stripping out all the path information except for the filename and I am setting the document hyperlink properties to be relative...

This works fine for firefox. When I open a document with a hyperlink and hover it shows the proper path `file:\\c:\path to file`. However in IE 8 the same file shows the path as `http://.../path to file`.

I am trying to convert a whole directory of word documents to html so that we can then put them on a disk and use fireant to serve them for a remote presentation.....

what am i doing wrong?

EDIT: as requested here is the source of one of the converted documents to HTML. It aint pretty...

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered)">
<base href="../">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Wingdings;
    panose-1:5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Cambria;
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
h1
    {margin-top:12.0pt;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:3.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:16.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    font-weight:normal;}
h2
    {margin-top:12.0pt;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:3.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:14.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:italic;}
h3
    {margin-top:12.0pt;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:3.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:13.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoToc1, li.MsoToc1, div.MsoToc1
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
p.MsoToc2, li.MsoToc2, div.MsoToc2
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:11.0pt;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
p.MsoCommentText, li.MsoCommentText, div.MsoCommentText
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
p.MsoTitle, li.MsoTitle, div.MsoTitle
    {margin-top:12.0pt;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:3.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:16.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
strong
    {font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    text-decoration:underline;}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
span.MsoBookTitle
    {font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-variant:small-caps;
    letter-spacing:.25pt;
    font-weight:bold;}
p.MsoTocHeading, li.MsoTocHeading, div.MsoTocHeading
    {margin-top:24.0pt;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    line-height:115%;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:14.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    color:#365F91;}
span.HeaderChar
    {mso-style-name:"Header Char";}
span.FooterChar
    {mso-style-name:"Footer Char";}
span.BalloonTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Balloon Text Char";
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}
p.Style1, li.Style1, div.Style1
    {mso-style-name:Style1;
    margin-top:12.0pt;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.25in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
span.Heading1Char
    {mso-style-name:"Heading 1 Char";
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
p.Style2, li.Style2, div.Style2
    {mso-style-name:Style2;
    margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:.65in;
    text-indent:-.4in;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
span.Heading2Char
    {mso-style-name:"Heading 2 Char";
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;}
span.TitleChar
    {mso-style-name:"Title Char";
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
span.Heading3Char
    {mso-style-name:"Heading 3 Char";
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
span.CommentTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Comment Text Char";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:10.0pt;}
 /* Page Definitions */
 @page Section1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.Section1
    {page:Section1;}
 /* List Definitions */
 ol
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
ul
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple>

<div class=Section1>

<p class=Style1 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:10.0pt;
margin-left:.25in'>1.<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>Transformational Leadership</p>

<p class=Style2><b>1.1.<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></b><b>Strategic Planning</b></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:1.25in;text-indent:-.6in'><b>1.1.1.<span
style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></b><b>TL1 - How nursing’s mission, vision, values, and strategic and
quality plans reflect the organization’s current and anticipated strategic
priorities. </b></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:-45.0pt'><b>1.1.1.A.<span
style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></b><b><u>Story</u>
– Nursing Strategic Plans Mirror Organizational Strategic Plans </b></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>True to Atlantic
General Hospital/Health System’s (AGH/HS) Collaborative Care Model, the nursing
department’s mission, vision, values, and strategic and quality plans mirror
those of our organization.  In 2005, nursing representatives were part of the
Values Committee that reviewed the organization’s mission, vision and values
and it was decided then that the nursing department’s mission, vision, and
values would be no different than that of the organization.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Our Mission</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>To provide quality
care, personalized service and education to improve individual and community
health.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Our Vision</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>To be the leader in
promoting access to healthcare services for the residents and visitors of
Worcester County and the surrounding region.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Our Values</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>We believe in
putting “PATIENTS” at the center of our values:</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;
margin-left:135.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:0in'>P ~ <i>Personalized
attention</i> </p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;
margin-left:135.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:0in'>A ~ <i>Accountability
for financial resources </i><br>
T ~ Try <i>respect and kindness</i> <br>
I ~ <i>Integrity, honesty &amp; trust</i> <br>
E ~ Education – <i>continued learning &amp; improvement</i> <br>
N ~ Needs of our community – <i>community commitment</i> </p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;
margin-left:135.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:0in'>T ~ <i>Teamwork
&amp; partnership</i> <br>
S ~ Safety first – <i>dedication to patient safety</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;
margin-left:135.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:0in'><i>&nbsp;</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;
margin-left:135.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:0in'>These values are
honored in all we do for our patients, visitors, medical staff, associates,
partners and volunteers.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;
margin-left:135.0pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:0in'>&nbsp;</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Organizational
Long-Term Strategic and Quality Plans</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>AGH/HS boasts of a
well-defined and well-integrated strategic planning process.  For a narrative
of this process, please refer back to the Organizational Overview Document
(OO3).</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="OO3%20Working%20Document.htm">OO3 Working Document.htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Five-year
organizational strategic and quality plans were initiated in 2005, shortly
after our current chief executive officer (CEO) took office.  At the outset,
many leaders were skeptical of this detailed and time-consuming course of
action, but as the reader will see, the AGH/HS strategic planning process soon
evolved into a dynamic and successful practice adopted by the entire
organization.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Following a
community needs assessment and an organization-wide analysis on AGH/HS
strengths, weaknesses, opportunities, and threats (SWOT), long-term strategic
and quality plans were constructed.  These plans were based on four quadrants
centered on individual and community health:  safe and effective care; access
and equity for all; timely and efficient care; and innovation and improvement. 
</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><img border=0
width=482 height=362 id="Picture 4"
src="file:///C:\Magnet\site\TL1%20thru%20TL3EO%20Working%20Document%20-%20Strategic%20Planning.12.30.09_files\image001.jpg"></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>From there, visions
for total health were built upon foundations within the existing AGH/HS
inpatient care delivery, emergency department care delivery, outpatient care
delivery, and physician practice network systems.  Plans for new services
included women’s health, orthopedics, cancer care, cardiac/vascular services,
pulmonary medicine, diabetes care, and wound care.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><img border=0
width=482 height=362 id="Picture 5"
src="file:///C:\Magnet\site\TL1%20thru%20TL3EO%20Working%20Document%20-%20Strategic%20Planning.12.30.09_files\image002.jpg"></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Patient Care
Services Strategic and Quality Plans</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Nursing’s strategic
and quality plans mirrored that of the organizational strategic plans.  The
existing structure of the inpatient care delivery systems was assessed using a
series of Registered Nurse (RN) surveys and SWOT analyses.  The result was a
strategic plan designed specifically for in-patient care to be developed as an
anchor service line, which incorporated disease specific service lines within
its definition.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Nursing recognized
the need to establish themselves as unique through outstanding customer
service, excellence in nursing, and exceptional in the utilization of information
and in the provision of quality clinical services.  The Magnet Recognition
Program was viewed as a roadmap toward obtaining this level of desired
excellence and Magnet Designation was incorporated into the strategic plan.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Expansion of
inpatient services was based on the integration of the following service
lines:  Joint Surgery Center (orthopedics), Stroke Center, Cancer and
Palliative care, Women’s Health Services, Cardiovascular and Pulmonary
services, and Progressive Care.  Adjunct services were to include Telemetry,
Dialysis, Wound Care and Pain Management.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Atlantic General
Hospital (AGH) Inpatient Care Services Strategic Plan</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Strategic%20Plan%202006%20-%20Inpatient.htm">Strategic Plan 2006 -
Inpatient.htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Detailed
descriptions of inpatient service lines were attached for Progressive Care and Stroke
Center.  However, the Joint Center, Palliative Care Service, Diabetes Care, Women’s
Health Center, Cardiovascular, Pulmonary, and Wound Care Center each had their
respective strategic plans.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Joint Center
Strategic Plan</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Strategic%20Plan%202006%20-%20Orthopaedic%20Services.htm">Strategic Plan
2006 - Orthopaedic Services.htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Palliative Care
Strategic Plan</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Palliative%20Care%20%20Strategic%20Plan%202008.htm">Palliative Care 
Strategic Plan 2008.htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Diabetes Care
Strategic Plan</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Opportunity%20Statement%20-%20Diabetes%20(Phase%20II).htm">Opportunity
Statement - Diabetes (Phase II).htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Women’s Health
Center Strategic Plan</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Strategic%20Plan%202006%20-%20Women's%20Health%202-7-06.htm">Strategic
Plan 2006 - Women's Health 2-7-06.htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Cardiovascular
Strategic Plan</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Strategic%20Plan%202006%20-%20Cardiovascular%202-8-06.htm">Strategic Plan
2006 - Cardiovascular 2-8-06.htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>&nbsp;</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>&nbsp;</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Pulmonary
Services Strategic Plan</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Strategic%20Plan%20-%20Pulmonary.htm">Strategic Plan - Pulmonary.htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Wound Care
Center</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Strategic%20Plan%202006%20-%20Wound%20Center.htm">Strategic Plan 2006 -
Wound Center.htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:-45.0pt'><b>1.1.1.B.<span
style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></b><b><u>Story</u>
-  Illustration of Nursing Strategic and Quality Plans Reflecting Those of the
Organization:  AGH 30 Minute Emergency Room (ER) Promise</b></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Despite a busy
summer season in 2007, AGH rolled out an innovative 30 Minute ER Promise.  Emergency
room overcrowding and long waits plague hospitals nationwide. Yet AGH’s
emergency department (ED) pulled off the shortest average wait times of any
hospital on Maryland’s Eastern Shore and achieved notable success with its
nurse-led “30 Minute ER Promise.”  This nursing strategic initiative is
reflective of the AGH/HS vision to be the leader in promoting access to
healthcare for the community.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>The hospital’s
pledge is that patients will be placed in an exam bed or begin to receive
treatment within 30 minutes of arrival at the hospital. That’s no easy feat for
an emergency department (ED) that sees more than 30,000 patients each year and
contends with an influx of vacationers each summer. The strategic initiative
went live in February 2007 and the department continues to meet the 30 minute
goal greater than 94 percent of the time.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Improving on
Good</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>“This was something
we could really capitalize on because we already had very good throughput
processes,” explains Andi West-McCabe, MS, BSN, RN, NE-BC, director of
emergency services. “A promise like this does a lot to reach out to our
community and inspire a sense of loyalty to the hospital. If patients come here
and have a good experience in the ER, then when it comes time to get their
preventive screens or their child care, they’ll come back to AGH/HS. Even the
vacationers end up returning.”</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>And to someone who
doesn’t have an extended vacation, the 30 minute promise seems pretty
attractive. Many out-of-towners are quite surprised at the treatment because
they’re accustomed to long waits at their local hospital.  “Vacationers talk
about how great it is to get in and out of our ER in a few hours. Just because
they cut their foot on a shell in the ocean doesn’t mean their vacation has to
be ruined,” said E. Belle Goslee, BSN, RN, FNE-A/P, clinical leader of the ED. </p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Patients know a
good thing when they see it. But the 30 minute rule isn’t all about marketing;
it’s about streamlining processes and capitalizing on teamwork to produce
quality care.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Making Ready </i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Before this project
could evolve, Atlantic General nurses had to identify what they could improve
upon and what barriers existed to achieving the 30 minute goal. </p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>“We looked at
everything,” West-McCabe said. “We outlined protocols so nurses could work
quickly based on the patient’s presentation. Now if a patient comes in with
chest pain, nurses automatically put them on the heart monitor, start oxygen or
an IV, get an electrocardiogram — all without missing a beat.” The protocols
also help everyone work together with little communication and confusion.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>“Our nurses are
excellent clinicians with superb clinical assessment skills — they’re able to
discern from the minute they triage the patient what the needs are,” Goslee
said. “The team concept is what makes our flow work so well. Everyone knows
what has to be done.”</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>The hospital also
started using an electronic patient tracking system. As soon as a patient
enters the ED, a staff member with a handheld pocket computer assesses that
individual’s reason for coming in. This information, entered into the handheld,
can be pulled up on any computer within the department, allowing the medical
staff to keep track and plan treatment before the patient enters the room.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>The ED also had to
reorganize some nursing roles, such as moving a veteran ED nurse into a manager
role to work on throughput and having a charge nurse available 24 hours a day
(previously they had them only 12 hours each day). They also added a unit
secretary position to take orders, answer the phone, make copies and chart if
the patient is being transferred.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Catching On</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Initially, the
nurse-driven initiative faced a challenge — garnering buy-in from the entire
staff, techs, physicians, even other departments.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>“One initial
difficulty was getting associates to understand why this was necessary. We
already had a lot of compliments from the community and within the hospital
about what a good job we did in the ED and how we saw the patients quicker than
other local facilities,” explained Jan Schaffner, BSN, RN, CEN, one of the ED
charge nurses. “That was our mindset at first: We do a good job, so why do we
need to change? Fortunately we had associates that were willing to go the extra
mile. We realized we were taking something we’re already good at and making it
excellent.”</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'> “Now the techs
will get started on vital signs right away; they don’t have to wait to hear ‘go
get this patient and bring him back.’ If they see on the system the patient is
present, they can start,” Schaffner said. “We looked at our processes and cut
out any unnecessary steps. And since people are able to spring into action, we
were able to prevent two major bottlenecks: patient’s waiting to be triaged and
patients waiting to see the physician.”</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Not Sacrificing
Quality </i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>Every person who
comes into the Atlantic General ED receives a rack card explaining the 30 minute
promise.  “The 30 minute timeframe begins the moment an individual comes
through the hospital’s doors until the time he or she is placed in an exam bed
or begins to receive treatment,” said West-McCabe. “It’s <i>not</i> from entry
to discharge.”</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>The average total
time spent in the Atlantic General ED for non-admission cases is 2 hours, 32
minutes. The average time spent for fast track visits is 1 hour, 14 minutes. </p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>That’s not to say
patients’ care is rushed at the cost of their wellbeing. “We’re able to cut out
unnecessary steps, eliminating unnecessary delays in treatment initiation,”
Goslee said. “We just put the urgency back in emergency.”</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>As for that 6
percent of patients who do happen to wait more than 30 minutes, they receive a
free gift as a thank you for their patience. Later a chart review occurs to see
how staff could have possibly prevented any delay.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>“We’ve now had
several years of success with this,” West-McCabe said. “We’ve been very blessed
to have an excellent team — every time we put something in front of them, they
step up to the challenge and want to do better.”</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>From submitting an
opportunity statement to developing a business plan to completing action plans,
AGH nurses stepped up to the plate and demonstrated enculturation of the AGH
mission, vision, and values through the implementation of these strategic and
quality initiatives.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>2006 Business
Plan for Emergency Services Expansion</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Strategic%20Plan%202006%20Final%20-%20Emergency%20Services%20Expansion-Andi%20(2).htm">Strategic
Plan 2006 Final - Emergency Services Expansion-Andi (2).htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Action Plan for
ER 30 Minute Promise as Strategic Initiative</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><a
href="Action%20Plan%20for%20Strategic%20Plan%2030%20Minute%20Promise%20(2).htm">Action
Plan for Strategic Plan 30 Minute Promise (2).htm</a></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:-45.0pt'><b>1.1.1.A.<span
style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></b><b><u>Story</u>
– Additional Illustration of Nursing Strategic Plans Reflecting Those of the
Organization:  Opening of our Wound Care Center</b></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:2.0in;text-indent:0in'>During the strategic
planning process in March 2006, the recommendation was made by patient care
services to evaluate the feasibility of developing a dedicated Wound Care
Center (WCC) to expand service lines, improve disease management, and enhance
patient satisfaction. The organization recognized the development of a WCC as
one of its anticipated strategic priorities and the strategic plan was developed
by staff, gaining administrative and approval by the Board of Directors (BOD) in
early 2007.</p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'><i>Establishing the
Need for a WCC</i></p>

<p class=Style2 style='margin-left:135.0pt;text-indent:0in'>The organization’s
mission, as well as nursing’s, it to provide quality care, personalized service
and education to improve individual and community health.  Understanding the
healthcare needs of the communi
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is produced as a result of your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tentative I have a lot more testing to do. but it appears that one browser or the other does not like the `<base href="../">` that is listed in the header. once I removed it it 'appears' that the relative links start working in both firefox and ie...ill update this if I find out more.